# Clear net.socket of any data

Tags: javascript, sockets, networking, server, system.net.sockets

I am writing a game server in node.js for an upcoming game that I am making. The game is written in another language (GML) and I am making the server in JavaScript. I use socket.write to send data to the client, however I don't want the previous string that I wrote in socket.write to be sent in the new message.

For exmaple:
socket.write("hello!");

The client will receive the string "hello!" succesfully.

However, upon using socket.write again, this will happen:

socket.write("hello again!"):

The client will receive the string "hello!hello again!". Why is this happening and is it possible to clear the socket of any remaining information before using socket.write again?

Server code:

```
var net = require("net");
var port = 3000;

var server = net.createServer();

let sockets = [];
playerID = 0; 

server.on("connection",function(socket)
{
    var addr = socket.remoteAddress;
    console.log("New Connection: " + addr);
    sockets.push(socket);
    playerID += 1;
    socket.ID = playerID;
    console.log(socket.ID);
    sockets.forEach((client) => {
        client.write("Player:Connected:" + socket.ID);
        console.log("Player:Connected:" + socket.ID);
    });
    socket.on("data",function(data)
    {
        console.log("data: " + data);
        if (data.includes("Client:Disconnected")) {
            console.log(socket.remoteAddress + " has disconnected");
            const index = sockets.indexOf(socket);
            if (index > -1) { 
                sockets.splice(index, 1); //remove client from socket list 
            }      
            //Notify the other clients of the disconnect event
            sockets.forEach((socket) => {
                socket.write("Player:Disconnected:" + socket.ID);
            });     
        };
    });

    socket.once("closed",function()
    {
        console.log("Player Disconnected: " + addr);
    });
});

server.listen(port,function()
{
    console.log("The Server has been Started on port " + port);
});
```

I tried googling this issue but to no avail, also tried using the docs but they didn't provide any information either.

Comment: I can't reproduce your observation.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Well, I mean what I wrote. What don't you understand?

Comment: Yes but what can't you reproduce exactly, I think it's self explanatory

Comment: I can't reproduce the outcome of your _exmaple: socket.write("hello!");

The client will receive the string "hello!" succesfully.

However, upon using socket.write again, this will happen:

socket.write("hello again!"):

The client will receive the string "hello!hello again!"._ - When I send "hello!", the server receives it, and I later send "hello again!", the server then receives "hello again!".

Comment: Maybe the error is in your client code?

Comment: Possible, let me send you exactly what I receive on my end!

Player:Connected:RawPlayer:Connected:1

As you can see, this is what I receive.
    socket.write("Player:Connected:Raw");                                                        
    sockets.forEach((client) => {
        client.write("Player:Connected:" + socket.ID);
    });
This is the order that I use socket.write in.

Comment: Where is this _socket.write("Player:Connected:Raw")_ code? I don't see it in your _Server code_.

Comment: At this point it doesn't matter, I rewrote the entire server in UDP and that fixed the issue.